# onListItemClick not firing in ListActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar, android-listfragment

In my main activity, I have an ActionBar with navigation tabs and action items.  One of my action items calls a ListFragment that displays a custom listview with an image and textview. I'm using ActionBarSherlock for compatability. Here is the code where I call the new ListFragment:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ERGProActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    case R.id.menuitem_search:
        onSearchRequested();
        return true;
    case R.id.menuitem_info:
        // Create new fragment and transaction
        SherlockListFragment aboutListFragment = new AboutListFragment();
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
        // and add the transaction to the back stack
        ft.replace(R.id.root, aboutListFragment);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        // Commit the transaction
        ft.commit();
        return true;

    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Here is my ListFragment code:

```
public class AboutListFragment extends SherlockListFragment {

    private ListView listView;

    @Override
     public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
         getActivity().setContentView(R.layout.aboutlist);

         CustomMenu menu_data[] = new CustomMenu[]
                { new CustomMenu(R.drawable.info, "About"),
                  new CustomMenu(R.drawable.legal, "Disclaimer"),};

                CustomMenuAdapter adapter = new CustomMenuAdapter(getActivity(), 
                        R.layout.listview_item_row, menu_data);
                listView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listView1);
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
     }

     @Override
     public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
         switch (position) {
         case 0:
             // about
             Log.i("ABOUT"," - About Selected");
         case 1:
             Log.i("ABOUT"," - Disclaimer Selected");
             // disclaimer
         }
     }
}
```

Here is my CustomAdapter code:

```
public class CustomMenuAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CustomMenu> {
    Context context; 
    int layoutResourceId;    
    CustomMenu data[] = null;

    public CustomMenuAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, CustomMenu[] data) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        CustomMenuHolder holder = null;

        if(row == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

            holder = new CustomMenuHolder();
            holder.imgIcon = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);
            holder.txtTitle = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);

            row.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (CustomMenuHolder)row.getTag();
        }

        CustomMenu menu = data[position];
        holder.txtTitle.setText(menu.title);
        holder.imgIcon.setImageResource(menu.icon);

        return row;
    }

    static class CustomMenuHolder
    {
        ImageView imgIcon;
        TextView txtTitle;
    }
}
```

Any input or suggestions would be appreciated! Thanks in advanced.

**Thanks everyone for your input!  Here is the final working code:**

```
 @Override
 public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
     getActivity().setContentView(R.layout.aboutlist);

     CustomMenu menu_data[] = new CustomMenu[]
            { new CustomMenu(R.drawable.info, "About"),
              new CustomMenu(R.drawable.legal, "Disclaimer"),};

            CustomMenuAdapter adapter = new CustomMenuAdapter(getActivity(), 
                    R.layout.listview_item_row, menu_data);
            listView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listView1);
            // listView.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {

                    switch (position) {
                             case 0:
                                 Log.i("ABOUT"," - About Selected");
                                 break;
                             case 1:
                                 Log.i("ABOUT"," - Disclaimer Selected");
                                 break;
                             default:
                                 // do nothing
                                 Log.i("ABOUT"," - default");
                                 break;
                                }
                    }
            });
    }
```

Comment: set  "focusable: false" of the textview and imageview.
I think it may work.

Comment: Do you only have two items in your listview?  Right now if you click on anything but the first two items in your list nothing will happen because of your switch statement.

Are you actually trying to get clicks from the textview or the image?

Comment: I was trying to get clicks from the listView.  I was able to get it to work and I did fix my switch/case statement as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```

try with this code.

Comment: Thanks for the Reply.  I was able to get it to work using a variation of onItemClick.  I'll post the working code for anyone else with simular situation.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code :

```
listView.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

after implementing methods, you get below methods:

```
@Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
Do your code here.....

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  I was able to get it to work using yogesh kamaliya suggestion.